# Vue3 Emit Event not triggering method in parent

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

After making an API call I want to stop a loading spinner from displaying. Before calling the child component I set the `this.showLoader` property to true. This displays the spinner graphic. However once the API call has been made the graphic does not disapear. The `updateLoader` method never gets called.

child.vue

```
export default {
  methods: {
    fetchData() { 
      fetch(url, options)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(this.$emit('hideLoaderEvent', false));
    }
  }
}
```

parent.vue

```
<template>
  <MyComponent @hideLoaderEvent="updateLoader" />
</template>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showLoader: false, 
  },
  methods: {
    updateLoader() {
        this.showLoader = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I created a [Vue Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-violet-7eygpu?file=/src/App.vue) with your logic, and it works fine. 

App.vue serves as your parent, and the logo will disappear when `updateLoader()` is called. 
HelloWorld.vue is your child and resolves a `Promise` after 3s to trigger the Event Emitter for `'hide-loader'`. 

Are you sure, that your Promise is being resolved properly?
I assume that it doesn't get called, because the Promise is not properly resolved.

Comment: Add a `console` before `this.$emit`.